# sql statement to chose the value of a field in the last entry

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a mysql database table which has two fields, `serial # (primary key, auto increment)` and `version.`

What I want to do is for every insert that I do to this database, set the `version` value to be 1, then 2, 3, 4, 5 and then back down to 1 again.

I can imagine doing this by pulling out the last entry in the table before doing an insert. How can I do this? Is there an easier way? I am using PHP.

Comment: Use a trigger? Write a procedure?

Comment: But how do you access the information in the last row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in MySQL Triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

You can create a database trigger to do what you want. The syntax is something like this:

```
CREATE
TRIGGER `event_name` BEFORE/AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE
ON `database`.`table`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    -- trigger body
    -- this code is applied to every
    -- inserted/updated/deleted row
END;
```

**Edit:**

Triggers are created directly in the database side. You can connect using the MySQL CLI or the PHPMyAdmin to run the query.

Also, a lazy solution may be to use a query similar to what aaaaaa123456789 suggested:

```
SELECT (
    (SELECT version FROM <table name here> ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1) % 5
) + 1 as version;
```

The modulos (%) operator returns the rest of the division of the two numbers and can be used to limit your increments.

Ex.:

```
 1 % 5 = 1
 2 % 5 = 2
 3 % 5 = 3
 5 % 5 = 0
 7 % 5 = 2 
10 % 5 = 0
```

PS.: I haven't tryed this query, 'cause I'm not on my dev machine, but from my mind it works.

Comment: Ok, I've never used triggers before. How does one create them with php? Is this 'create trigger' statement just viewed as a normal sql statement and you would use the syntax mysql_query()?

Comment: @user1015214 Please, don't use `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated.  Use `mysqli_` or `PDO`. Further, triggers are handled on the database side.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is, as rcdmk suggested, to write a trigger in the database itself, that updates the version field with the corresponding value.

If a trigger is just out of the window for any reason, then you could just do `SELECT version FROM <table name here> ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1` to get the last value. In fact, bracketting that (as in, putting it between parentheses) and sending `1 + (query here)` to the `INSERT` query as the insertion value is probably the best way to do it, since it avoids race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$next_increment     = 0; 
$qShowStatus         = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'yourtable'"; 
$qShowStatusResult     = mysql_query($qShowStatus) or die ( "Query failed: " . mysql_error() . "<br/>" . $qShowStatus ); 

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qShowStatusResult); 
$next_increment = $row['Auto_increment'];
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_` functions. All this answer does is provide the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value. What next?

Comment: yeah now you know the last ID and then get the result by using another select quey.you can do what ever you want.